# why a click event in javascript is removing a list item on second clik only

Tags: javascript, removechild

trying to remove a list item with a button click event but list is only deleted after the second click.

```
    <section class="score-panel">

    <ul id="lives">
        <li>life11</li>
        <li>life2</li>
        <li>life3</li>
    </ul>
    <button onclick="lostLives()">Remove list item</button>
    </section>
```

and the javascript function looks like

```
let lostLives = function() {
    let lives = document.getElementById('lives');
    lives.removeChild(lives.lastChild);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to demonstrate why there is a deletion on every second key press, change your script to this:

```
let lives = document.getElementById('lives');
console.log(lives);
let lostLives = function() {
    lives.removeChild(lives.firstElementChild);
};
```

If you view your page in a browser and open up the console, you then can view the child nodes as follows:

[image]

You will notice that there are 7 nodes, not the expected 3 because the text and the element nodes are children of *ul#lives*. Starting at the bottom, there is a text node first so this will be deleted when the button is pressed, followed by the li element, then text etc. which is exactly what you see.

As a further example, if you change your html to be as follows:

```
<section class="score-panel">
    <ul id="lives"><li>life11</li><li>life2</li><li>life3</li></ul>
    <button onclick="lostLives()">Remove list item</button>
</section>
```

Then you will find that there are only 3 child nodes and your function will work as you expected it to work.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`lastChild` [will give you text nodes or comment nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild), not just element nodes. In this case, it's giving you a text node corresponding to the whitespace after the last `<li>`.

You want `lastElementChild`, which only gives you elements.

```js
let lostLives = function() {
    let lives = document.getElementById('lives');
    lives.removeChild(lives.lastElementChild);
};
```

```html
<section class="score-panel">

  <ul id="lives">
    <li>life11</li>
    <li>life2</li>
    <li>life3</li>
  </ul>
  <button onclick="lostLives()">Remove list item</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

change the .lastChild to .lastElementChild and your function will work.  The last child is a text node with the spaces tabs and carriage returns, the last element is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below one

```js
let lostLives = function() {
  let lives = document.getElementById('lives');
  lives.removeChild(lives.lastElementChild);
};
```

```html
<section class="score-panel">

  <ul id="lives">
    <li>life11</li>
    <li>life2</li>
    <li>life3</li>
  </ul>
  <button onclick="lostLives()">Remove list item</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

> `lastChild` is not element but `text` node. You should be using `lastElementChild` as you are trying to remove `li` element node.

```js
let lostLives = function() {
  let lives = document.getElementById('lives');
  lives.removeChild(lives.lastElementChild);
};
```

```html
<section class="score-panel">

  <ul id="lives">
    <li>life11</li>
    <li>life2</li>
    <li>life3</li>
  </ul>
  <button onclick="lostLives()">Remove list item</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var lostLives = document.getElementById("lostLives");

lostLives.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var el = document.getElementById('lives');
    if (el.children.length > 0) {  
       el.removeChild(el.lastElementChild);
    }else{
        alert("All items have been deleted");
    }
});
```

```html
    <section class="score-panel">

    <ul id="lives">
        <li>life11</li>
        <li>life2</li>
        <li>life3</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="lostLives">Remove list item</button>
    </section>
```